# GSM notation for a visited network

Tags: gsm

i would like to know how to write the notation when a mobile entity turns on in a foreign network in respect to GSM protocol.

I was able figure out for inter-domain, but i would like to know what happens when a mobile entity turns on in a foreign network, How is the key establishment and exchange is done between the HLR and VLR.

Please advice.

Comment: Have you looked at 3GPP TS 29.002?